# How to stop this array of attributes from showing in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I have an annoying problem where my view keeps displaying an array of my object's attributes! My submenu is suppose to show categories in a tree form, which works, but it also shows this annoying array!

> [ <#Category id: 26, title: "subtest", description: "a test within a test, testception", created_at: "2015-03-01 03:15:29", updated_at: "2015-03-03 01:08:09", ancestry: "6/24">]
>
> [ <#Category id: 24, title: "Test", description: "No not be alarmed, this is only a test.", created_at: "2015-03-01 02:06:35", updated_at: "2015-03-03 01:07:52", ancestry: "6">]

I definately don't want the user to see this. How do I get rid of it??

Show.html.erb view:

```
<div id="submenu">
  <%= render 'submenu_cats', categories: @category.root.children %>
</div>
```

_submenu cats partial:

```
<ul>
  <%= categories.each do |category| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to_unless_current category.title, category_path %>
        <%= render 'submenu_cats', categories: category.children if category.children.present? %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

Using: Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1.5, Ancestry Gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use...

```
<%= categories.each do |category| %>
```

Use

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
```

When you use `<%=`, you're outputting the result of the expression. The result of `categories.each` is `categories`, the array that is being output. You don't want to output it, so use `<%` to evaluate the Ruby without outputting the results.

Comment: Awesome! The answer was so obvious haha, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<%= %>` which means that you are outputting the results of a Ruby code, instead use `<% %>` to executes the ruby code within the brackets.

So change

```
<%= categories.each do |category| %>
```

To

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
```

Hope this help. :)